# A referential integrity constraint violation occurred Nullable FK

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a nullable int as a fk in my table as seen below. I have made the FK int?. But if i attempt to save with a null value a get a referencial constraint error?

```
  [Table("Tests")]
  public class Tests : BaseEntity 
  {
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public virtual string TestName { get; set; }

    public virtual int? ProjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
  }       

 [Table("Project")]
  public class Project : BaseEntity
  {
    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(200)]
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
  }

  public class BaseEntity 
  {
    [Key, Required]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
  }

  _testsRepo.InsertOrUpdateAndGetId(test);
```

**Exception :**

> System.InvalidOperationException: A referential integrity constraint
>   violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Project.Id' on one end
>   of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of
>   'Tests.ProjectId' on the other end.

Comment: can you show full exception ?

Comment: can you show the code of `Project` model also ?

Comment: Its my understanding that making the fk a int? should be all that's required

Comment: And need to show the `Save` method's code also ?

Comment: Its using a repo pattern that i do not have teh source code for, but as i call it   _testsRepo.InsertOrUpdateAndGetId(tests);

Comment: OK,can you show your `test` object here `_testsRepo.InsertOrUpdateAndGetId(test);` ? How did you construct it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125313/discussion-between-jeepers-and-sampath).

Answer (score 1):

So the Issue was in the AutoMapper code I needed the following line

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ProductId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ProductId))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Product, opts => opts.Ignore());
```